# How to align all objects in the center of the artboard using Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, artboard, shortcuts

Is there a shortcut to align all objects in the center of an artboard instead of doing it manually?

Comment: Make sure you have at least 2 element selected

Comment: If align to artboard is on then even one object is enough

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yes. Simply choose `Align to Artboard` in the Align Panel or Control Bar.

[image]

[image]

Then click the various align buttons.

Comment: I have a rectangle selected but align buttons have no effect, any suggestion? Illustrator CC 17.1

Comment: In Adobe CC 2014 - you do not have the `Align to` section on the pop-up but it does appear on the tool bar

Comment: Align to selection is still present on the Panel. That has never changed. Not sure what you're seeing @UjjwalSingh

Comment: I just posted an answer for you since I am also using CC version. ;)

Comment: Pay attention that the selection or group that are trying to align, doesn't have guides.

Comment: This alignment has only effect if you are using the `Selection Tool (V)`, not with the `Direct Selection Tool (A)`.

Comment: @NickeManarin that depends largely on *how* you use the Direct Selection Tool --- click the middle of a shape's fill and this method works just fine with the Direct Selection Tool. Click a specific anchor or path along a shape, and this method won't work as well. And.. you can always simply hold the Option/Alt key down with teh Direct Selection Tool to select an entire object as opposed to part of an object.

Comment: @Scott Ahh, thanks. I was selecting a simple line, but not clicking on any anchor, just on the stroke. That's why it was not working with DST, only with ST.

Answer (score 24):

In CC, press the pop-out menu to enable the additional options. Select "Show Options"

[image: Select "Show Options"]

Select the "Align To" button and choose "Align to Artboard."

[image: Select "Align to Artboard"]

After that, any objects you select and use "Align to Center" will be aligned with the center of the currently active artboard.

Answer (score 0):

CoolSelection plugin for Illustrator will do it.
Select the objects You want to align, then press **Shift + 0** to align them to the center of the artboard.
https://www.cool-selection.com/index.html#align
This answer was written by the author of CoolSelection.

Comment: Why when AI has buttons built in? And you *could* create actions with your own shortcuts. This *really* looks like spam.

Comment: @Scott
1. Clicking a button with a mouse is not the same as a keyboard shortcut. CorelDraw has built-in single button shortcuts for alignment. People switching from CorelDraw to Illustrator miss them a lot.
2. You may record or download alignment actions and add shortcuts to them. But there is another problem: You can't record an action that switches between "Align to selection/Align to key object/Align to artboard". An action will work differently for different "Align to" settings. You still need to click to change them.
Just pressing a button looks much simpler.